# can't set image for Bar Button Item

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm using Objective-C. In Xcode, I set a image(.png) to a navigation bar button item. But no matter how I change the resolution of the image, it always going to be a blue pic, big or small.

It looks like this(the right top corner):

[image]

Does the picture cause the problem? How to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please check answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of Barbutton's size is fixed.

So , my advice is add UIView as Barbutton item and then add UIButton and set image According to your required size.

Check output in below image.

[image]

Your Hierarchy will be something like this ,

[image]